# How to send notification to user/machine in enterprise setting?

Tags: powershell, notifications, signalr, system, enterprise

Current Situation:
I created a powershell script that can draw a toast-like notification on the lower right side of the screen. My only problem is that this only works on the local computer. How Do I make this notification show up on a target machine? Just by specifying the machine name in the Active Directory ?

Of course I'm open to other suggestions. I'm currently reading up on SignalR but I'm not sure how to make SignalR work on native desktop , and not through a website. Perfect situation would be a Notification System that can mass send toast notifications in Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Here is my current script

```
Function ShowNotification
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
           [string] $Title,
           [string] $Message,
           [string] $Image,
           [string] $Hyperlink 
    )
    Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework, System.Windows.Forms

         $screenHeight = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenHeight
         $screenWidth = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth

         ############################ NOTIFICATION CLIENT GUI #########################################

$XAML2 = @'
<Window Name="Form2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
        Title="Notification" Height="141.071" Width="504.611" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#313130">
    <Window.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </Window.Effect>
    <Grid Margin="-99,133.5,-102,54" Background="#313130">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="238*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="190*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="55*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="132*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="TitleLabel" Content="HEY" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,-127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="388" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Regular" FontSize="18"  FontFamily="Segoe UI SemiLight"/>
        <Path Data="M99,-92.5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="99,-92.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"/>
        <Image Name="imageBox" Source="<PictureSource>" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="0,-114,0,-6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MessageTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,-87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="80" Width="382" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="14"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


'@

[xml]$XAML2 = $XAML2 -replace "<PictureSource>", $Image

        ###############################################################################################

        ############################# CONVERT GUI COMPONENTS TO VARIABLES #############################
        $script:window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml2))
        $xaml2.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Script }
        ###############################################################################################

        ############################# EVENT HANDLERS ##################################################
        $window.Add_MouseDown({

            If($Image)
            {
                $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($Image);

                $form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
                $form.Text = "Image Viewer"
                $form.Width = $img.Size.Height;
                $form.Height =  $img.Size.Width;
                $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

                $pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
                $pictureBox.Dock = "Fill"
                $pictureBox.SizeMode = "Zoom"
                $pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
                $pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height;

                $pictureBox.Image = $img;
                ### HYPERLINK WHEN CLICKING PICTURE ###
                <#
                If ($img -and $Hyperlink)
                {
                    $pictureBox.Add_Click({
                                ### Opens up IE
                                $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
                                $ie.Navigate($Hyperlink)
                                $ie.Visible = $true
                    })
                }#>

                $form.controls.add($pictureBox)
                $form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
                $form.ShowDialog()
            }

            If ($Hyperlink)
            {
                                $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
                                $ie.Navigate($Hyperlink)
                                $ie.Visible = $true
            }

            $window.Close()
        })

    $TitleLabel.Content = $Title
    $MessageTB.Text = $Message

    $window.Left = $([System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Width-$window.Width)
    $window.Top = $([System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Height-$window.Height)

$timer = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 20000
$timer.Add_Tick({
 $timer.Stop();
    #$timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(formClose_Tick);
$window.Close()
})

$timer.Start()
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

}
```

Comment: well, can you share the script? how are you invoking a toast notification?

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following a loong time ago (it works on remote machines - a user has to be signed in on the machine before the toast messages work, but it doesn't matter if the console is locked - they just need to be signed in). (I shouldn't post this since the topic starter didn't supply his/her own code, but I'll make an exception this time). Keep in mind that I have a variable $cred in this script which is not set as a parameter (this variable contains admin credentials because of Invoke-Command to a remote machine).

```
Function Invoke-ToastMessage
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param
        (
        [string]$Message,
        [string]$Notifier = "Administrators",
        [string]$ComputerName = $null
        )

[scriptblock]$ToastScriptRemote = {
$Message = $args[0]
$Notifier = $args[1]
# XML Template
[xml]$XmlTemplate = @"
<toast scenario="reminder">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Admin Notification</text>
      <text>$Message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
  </actions>
</toast>
"@
    # fake load the assemblies
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification,Windows.UI.Notifications,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument,Windows.Data.Xml.Dom,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    $FinalXML = [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]::new()
    $FinalXML.LoadXml($XmlTemplate.OuterXml)
    ## create the toast
    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($FinalXML)
    ## Show the TOAST message
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($Notifier).show($Toast)
    }

[scriptblock]$ToastScriptLocal = {
# XML Template
[xml]$XmlTemplate = @"
<toast scenario="reminder">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Admin Notification</text>
      <text>$Message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
  </actions>
</toast>
"@
    # fake load the assemblies
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification,Windows.UI.Notifications,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument,Windows.Data.Xml.Dom,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    $FinalXML = [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]::new()
    $FinalXML.LoadXml($XmlTemplate.OuterXml)
    ## create the toast
    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($FinalXML)
    ## Show the TOAST message
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($Notifier).show($Toast)
    }

if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ComputerName))
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $ToastScriptRemote -ArgumentList $Message,$Notifier
    }
    else {$ToastScriptLocal.Invoke()}
}
```

Comment: Hi. Does this work? Because i know that calling invoke-command runs scripts fine BUT they do not allow scripts that show GUIs to pop up

Comment: @bluff I just tested it! It does work. Wow. I really thought you wouldn't be able to run remote scripts with GUIs on it. is there a way to modify the toast that shows up so that we can have like a button that can open a webpage, or show an image etc? Thanks!

Comment: You can embed images (UNC shares won't work, mapped drives do work however) and use built-in Windows sounds. Adding buttons is also possible but since you can't hook them to something they are pretty useless. See the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts for info about how to form the XML to have images etc in them.

Comment: HI Bluff. First of all thanks so much for taking the time to reply. Secondly, there doesn't seem to be a way to handle the button events??? I know that powershell cannot subscribe to WinRT events, but I found this guy who created a .NET wrapper for WinRT events so that powershell can subscribe to them. Perhaps you could take a look and help me out? I can't figure out how to make it work though. 

https://deletethis.net/dave/2016-06/WinRT+Toast+from+PowerShell